# Why my PWA doesn't work on Safari and opera? It shows "can't establish a secure connection to the server"

Tags: firebase, ssl, web, progressive-web-apps

I'm making a PWA and is hosted on Firebase. I can see my page in Chrome, IE and other browsers. But I have problems with Safari and Opera.  I have SLL certificade and TLS 1.2 (both from firebase) with nginx as server.

I tested my page on browsers and  I  get errors like:

"Safari can't open the page -url- besause safari can't establish a
   secure connection to the server -url-" 
"Can't establish
   communication    with protocol SSL/ TLS"
"Fatal Error (70) from
   server "    (Opera/Debian)

And in htbridge I got:

- *HTTPS protocol, failed CSP status
  *Many "The header was not sent by the server."
  *I don't have have a Certification Authority Authorization (CAA) record.
  *No support of TLSv1.3
  *Server doesn't provide HPKP

So, I guess is something about security. But I don't know why it can be the main problem.

I tried to correct some stuff  some commands on the server (nginx) but I don't know where is that or what I need to do. I am new to these things and I need someone to guide me a little at this point.

What should I do or is something I don't know?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Opera is exactly following the footsteps of Chrome, so if it works on Chrome shouldn't be problem on Opera, i would say just uninstall the Opera and re-install it. Also, check what versions you have got? to get he maximum of both browsers you need latest versions. Also, there are certain restrictions on Safari regarding PWA and service worker. Although, both Safari and MS Edge working on it and all the main browsers are getting into the same page on the issue of PWA (i.e. Service worker, Cache Api and IndexedDB).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was testing on obsolete versions of Safari and Opera for Windows. For some reason it did'nt work on a specific iphone and hence my confusion. Thank you for your help!